# Creating positive definite matrix correlation matrix

Tags: correlation, mixed-model, covariance-matrix

This question is moved from the computational science stackexchange: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/34659/creating-positive-definite-matrix?noredirect=1#comment64520_34659

I'm trying to create a big (50.000x50.000) positive definite correlation matrix . The matrix should be correlations of effects on phenotypes ascribable to people sharing the same environment. I have data indicating who lives together. So my idea was to say that people who have lived together have correlations of 0.5. And if you have lived together with someone one step out you get correlation 0.25 i.e. if A and B both have lived with C but A and B have not lived together. And so I continue going 6 steps out and halving the coefficient each step. I have 1's in the diagonal.

The problem is that the matrix is not positive definite, which it has to be for my software/model to work (I'm using wombat to fit a linear mixed model). Do anyone know how to ensure that a correlation matrix is in fact positive definite?

Comment: I think you want to use the graph Laplacian to generate the corresponding diffusion matrix. The correlation $\rho$ will be associated with the initial conditions.

Comment: Do you mean like a Incidence matrix? I need to end up with a matrix representing correlations